# How do I pass the submit button's value from another component to the FinalForm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, jsx, react-props

I am new to REACT and have gotten this rather big assignment. Would really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

So I may need a little bit more clarification. Can you post full snippets of the code? Maybe full files will help.

The main thing that might help is simply creating the input state and form state on the final form level and pass them into the search bar where the inputs and button lives.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look. I have posted the complete snippets.